# Resuming a download using Internet Download Manager

Tags: download, file-transfer

I use IDM (Internet Download Manager version 5.18 Build 8) to download files, but when I download a file from MediaFire.com, the connection is sometimes cut.

When I try to resume the downloading, the following message is shown:

> the website send a web page instead of a file when IDM requested this file second time

Is there any way to resume the partial download without having to restart the download from the beginning?

Comment: It would be interesting to know this in a more general context. Why does this happen sometime with or without a download manager, not just on [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/) and sometimes also on the first try not just when resuming.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not with the IDM. The actual problem with the download server as MediaFire, RapidShare etc sites provide resume only if you have the premium accounts on that sites and if you have not the premium account and you are using free account to download then they will not give you resume option in their download. The IDM shows the resume capability is supported or not from the downloading link. As in the picture you can see the resume is supported by the downloaded file if it doesn't then the resume capability option would be written in red color "NO".

[image]

If you look at the [differences between account types](https://www.mediafire.com/select_account_type.php), you see the paid ones providing direct downloads, while the free service doesn't. Resume support and multiple download threads (via a download manager) work only for their direct downloads.

Comment: I download video, and it is resumeable. But, 403 or forbidden. I try to copy paste download information like link, referer, user and password from new same download file and no luck. It will always ask new download link, even I have set it exactly same with new same file download

Answer (score 2):

Probably this site uses temporary links that cannot be requested twice or expire after some time when session is completed.

To resume such download please right click on a download in IDM list and select "Refresh download address" from the popup menu.

Then IDM will show the following dialog and will try to open a web page where you found initial download link. If IDM fails to open correct web page, or recognize a download link, open correct web page manually in your browser.

On this page, start downloading the same link again. IDM will detect that this is the new link that it is waiting for and show the following message.

If IDM fails to recognize a link, it will ask you if this is a new download link that it waiting for. Tell it that this is a new link.

Then you can resume the download.

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the previous download and start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me (tried to download a torrent file via external websites so that you can download it faster with IDM) Here is how i fixed my issue

when you change your internet Access point or something happen you may recieve the above error for that you should

right click on the half downloaded file > go to properties > there you can see 'address' now delete the address in the address bar and

go to your browser and > go to the website which you hosted your torrent file copy the DOWNLOAD url from the website (not the url of the website) and paste it in the IDM > YOUR DOWNLOAD > PROPERTIES > ADDRESS BAR

click OK

and resume your download :)

Answer (score -1):

Try deactivating your firewall for both the public and private networks for the mean time till the download is done

Comment: How does doing this address the problem?